# Iron-Router route arbitrary method

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

Is it possible to have a route that doesnt render any template and just does something?

This is the functionality I am looking for:

```
this.route( {
    path: '/something/:info1/:info2',
    method: function() { 
        // do something with this.params.info1 and this.params.info2
        Router.go('elsewhere');
    },
});
```

If not, is there a way of achieving this functionality?

Comment: You could extract the info1 and info2 from location.href..

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can override the default action in the route. The default action for the route is the `run` method of RouteController. You override it in 0.5.4 by providing a `handler` option to the route. In the dev branch you just provide an `action` option. The default action renders the main template and then renders all the yield templates into their proper locations. But your action function can do whatever you'd like, including not rendering any templates at all. I'll show the 0.5.4 and dev examples:

**v0.5.4**

```
this.route({
  path: '/something/:info/:info2',
  handler: function () {
    var info = this.params.info;
    var info2 = this.params.info2;
    this.redirect('elsewhere', {
      //optional context object which could include params
    });
  }
});
```

**dev branch:**

```
this.route({
  path: '/something/:info/:info2',
  action: function () {
    var info = this.params.info;
    var info2 = this.params.info2;
    this.redirect('elsewhere', {
      //optional context object which could include params
    });
  }
});
```